# Is there a formula for this summation $\sum\limits_{k=i}^\mathbb{N}{i}$?

Tags: summation

Is there a formulae for this summation?
I wonder this could be not a constant or to say that i * i?

$\sum\limits_{k=i}^\mathbb{N}{i}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{k=i}^N i = i \sum\limits_{k=i}^N 1 = i(N - i + 1)$$

Maybe you meant:
$$\sum\limits_{k=i}^N k = \sum\limits_{k=1}^N k - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{i-1}k = \frac{N(N+1)}2 - \frac{i(i-1)}2$$

Comment: you actually right at first so if I a going to say $$\sum\limits_{k=g}^\mathbb{N}{g} = \sum\limits_{k=g}^\mathbb{N}{1} = g ( N - g + 1 ) $$ is this is right?

Comment: The result is right but not the intermediary sum (it misses a $g$).

Comment: so what can I do to make it correct?

Comment: I used this formula for counting repetitive for shell short and I got this

$10\sum\limits_{k=1}^N g + \sum\limits_{k=1}^N 2 + 4n + 2$

Comment: the ${g}$ is the gap or interval